# java How do I convert a string that is FormatStyle.MEDIUM ("Nov 30, 2016") to a LocalDateTime type?

Tags: java

In java if I have a String that looks like this: "Nov 30, 2016" (this is FormatStyle.MEDIUM), how do I convert it into a LocalDateTime data type?

Answer (score 0):

I ran this on JDK 8:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;

public class DateFormatDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateStr = "Nov 30, 2016";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM));
        System.out.println("date string: " + dateStr);
        System.out.println("local date : " + ldt);
    }
}
```

Here's my output:

```
date string: Nov 30, 2016
local date : 2016-11-30

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I got an exception with the original code using `LocalDateTime`, because the input `String` didn't include a time.

If you'd like `LocalDateTime`, try adding `hh:mm:ss` to the input.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and this is not working: 'Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Nov 30, 2016' could not be parsed at index 0'

Comment: You get that error if you try to parse a date without time as LocalDateTime.

Comment: How would then your code look like without errors?

Comment: Just as I modified above.  That works for me.  If you want LocalDateTime, please do some work for yourself.

Comment: Nope, just LocalDate. The edit is still not working. I run it with **jdk-11.0.1.**